# Matlab, Adjust Image perspective to clear the depth

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a project of image processing and at the moment I am dealing with the adjustment of the perspective of an image like this:
[image: example image]

I would like to have the race track on a 2d plane taking out the perspective.

I have seen at this link http://classes.engr.oregonstate.edu/engr/spring2011/engr421-001/group/gp1/finaldesign/software.html a possible solution to my problem which is almost the same of my case but I couldn't be able to solve it. 
Resuming, in that link they perform a projective transformation with 4 control points pairs and then an affine transformation. The result is exactly what I want. I didn't understand how to perform the projective transformation around the 4 points.

Anyone can give me an advice?

Comment: Could you please give us some MWE of how your image and data is looking like (do you have: positions of markers in your image, positions of your markers in the 3D world, ...?). Otherwise I can only guess what we are talking about: You have 4 markers, which you can automatically identify (incl. 2D pos.) in the orig. image. Then you know where they should be (from your positioning in real world). Then you find an affine transformation A (4 dofs in 2D) which maps the identified positions to the apriori positions and apply A to your whole image... for more fancy stuff follow e.g. Hartley/Zissorman

Comment: Hi,
I have changed my post and I added the image on which I have to change the perspective. I want to see the race track on a 2d plane. I can get the 4 markers on the race track parallel vertical lines by using the hough transform which detect those lines. How you can get the image with the projective transformation as in the project of the oregon state. Can you post some code?